# Error in network definition at netcfg.yaml file: unknown key tunnels

Tags: 18.04, configuration, netplan, tunnel

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 bionic.

when I try to configure GRE Tunnel in the netcfg.yaml file I encounter an error:

Error in network definition //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line x column x: unknown key tunnels.

The yaml configuration looks like this:

[image: Yaml configuration screenshot]

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens01:
        addresses : [10.201.x.yyy/24]
        gateway4: 10.201.x.254  
        nameservers:
            addresses: [10.200.nn.tt]
        dhcp4: no
    ens02:
        dhcp4: no
        addresses : [10.200.aa.dd/24]
        routes:
        - to: 10.200.hh.0/24
          via: 10.200.aa.254 

  tunnels: 
    gre1: 
        mode: gre
        local: 10.200.aa.dd
        remote: 10.200.hh.cc
        addresses: 
          - 172.26.jj.14/32
        gateway4: 172.26.jj.13
```

What is the right way to configure GRE Tunnel on Ubuntu?

A similar yaml configuration, but I still got the same error:

[image: Yaml configuration-2 screenshot]

The error is: `Error in network definition line 3 column 2: unknown key tunnels`

The netplan version is:

[image: Netplan version]

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks! Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I still have the Error in network definition because unknown key tunnels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct .yaml needs to look **EXACTLY** like this... **exact spacing, indentation, no trailing spaces, and no tabs**... suggest copy/paste, then edit addresses... (redacting the addresses is unnecessary and creates errors)...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens01:
      addresses: [10.201.x.yyy/24]
      gateway4: 10.201.x.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.200.nn.tt]
      optional: true
    ens02:
      addresses: [10.200.aa.dd/24]
      routes:
        - to: 10.200.hh.0/24
          via: 10.200.aa.254
      optional: true
  tunnels:
    gre1:
      mode: gre
      local: 10.200.aa.dd
      remote: 10.200.hh.cc
      addresses:
        - 172.26.jj.14/32
      gateway4: 172.26.jj.13
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

You have a very old version of netplan installed, and it may not support tunnels. Update netplan, or update your OS.

Comment: Thanks heynnema, but still have the Error in network definition because unknown key tunnels.

Comment: @Yisrael Please edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` exactly as it is now, with no redaction's.

Comment: @Yisrael Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *netplan*`.

Comment: I've added the information to the question.

Comment: @Yisrael Screenshots aren't a good idea for text that should be copy/pasted into your question. You did **not** use my exact .yaml file as instructed, as you still have "Addresses :", and your indentation is wrong. You must use 2 space indents ALL the way through the .yaml. Also, your netplan is very old, and may not even support tunnels yet. Fix the .yaml, retest, and if required, update your netplan or OS.

Comment: @Yisrael Install `yamllint` and run your .yaml file through it to find errors.

Comment: @Yisrael Status please...

Comment: I've upgraded the Netplan version and it solved the problem. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In yaml, indentation matters.  The config you've pasted in your question shows two spaces of indentation for `ethernets:` and three spaces for `tunnels:`, which means this is treated as a child of ethernets instead of as a sibling, and there is no known key `tunnels` which is valid under `ethernets`.  Correct this so that they both have the same level of indentation, and this should work.

Comment: Thanks slangasek, but the indentation is correct and it's not the issue this case.

Comment: I've checked again the indentation and it was found correct, unfortunately the  error is still there.